# Tensorflow- How to display accuracy rate for a linear regression model

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, tensorflow, linear-regression

I have a linear regression model that seems to work. I first load the `data` into `X` and the target column into `Y`, after that I implement the following...

```
X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = train_test_split(
    X_data, 
    Y_data, 
    test_size=0.2
)

rng = np.random

n_rows = X_train.shape[0]

X = tf.placeholder("float")
Y = tf.placeholder("float")


W = tf.Variable(rng.randn(), name="weight")
b = tf.Variable(rng.randn(), name="bias")

pred = tf.add(tf.multiply(X, W), b)

cost = tf.reduce_sum(tf.pow(pred-Y, 2)/(2*n_rows))

optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(FLAGS.learning_rate).minimize(cost)



init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
init_local = tf.local_variables_initializer()

with tf.Session() as sess:

    sess.run([init, init_local])

    for epoch in range(FLAGS.training_epochs):

        avg_cost = 0

        for (x, y) in zip(X_train, Y_train):

            sess.run(optimizer, feed_dict={X:x, Y:y})

        # display logs per epoch step
        if (epoch + 1) % FLAGS.display_step == 0:

            c = sess.run(
                cost, 
                feed_dict={X:X_train, Y:Y_train}
            )

            print("Epoch:", '%04d' % (epoch + 1), "cost=", "{:.9f}".format(c))

    print("Optimization Finished!")

    accuracy, accuracy_op = tf.metrics.accuracy(labels=tf.argmax(Y_test, 0), predictions=tf.argmax(pred, 0))

    print(sess.run(accuracy))
```

I cannot figure out how to print out the model's accuracy. For example, in `sklearn`, it is simple, if you have a model you just print `model.score(X_test, Y_test)`. But I do not know how to do this in `tensorflow` or if it is even possible.

I think I'd be able to calculate the `Mean Squared Error`. Does this help in any way?

**EDIT**

I tried implementing `tf.metrics.accuracy` as suggested in the comments but I'm having an issue implementing it. The documentation says it takes 2 arguments, `labels` and `predictions`, so I tried the following...

```
accuracy, accuracy_op = tf.metrics.accuracy(labels=tf.argmax(Y_test, 0), predictions=tf.argmax(pred, 0))

print(sess.run(accuracy))
```

But this gives me an error...

> FailedPreconditionError (see above for traceback): Attempting to use uninitialized value accuracy/count
>        [[Node: accuracy/count/read = IdentityT=DT_FLOAT, _class=["loc:@accuracy/count"], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"]]

How exactly does one implement this?

Comment: what about `tf.metrics.accuracy` which returns a Tensor representing the `accuracy`, the value of total divided by count? And MSE isn't going to tell you the accuracy score.

Comment: @Flika205 I am trying to implement it but I am getting errors. See my edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading the complete code you posted, I noticed a couple other things:

- In your calculation of `pred`, you use 
  `pred = tf.add(tf.multiply(X, W), b)`. `tf.multiply` performs element-wise multiplication, and will not give you the fully connected layers you need for a neural network (which I am assuming is what you are ultimately working toward, since you're using TensorFlow). To implement fully connected layers, where each layer i (including input and output layers) has n<sub>i</sub> nodes, you need separate weight and bias matrices for each pair of successive layers. The dimensions of the i-th weight matrix (the weights between the i-th layer and the i+1-th layer) should be (n<sub>i</sub>, n<sub>i + 1</sub>), and the i-th bias matrix should have dimensions (n<sub>i + 1</sub>, 1). Then, going back to the multiplication operation - replace tf.multiply with tf.matmul, and you're good to go. I assume that what you have is probably fine for a single-class linear regression problem, but this is definitely the way you want to go if you plan to solve a multiclass regression problem or implement a deeper network.
- Your weight and bias tensors have a shape of (1, 1). You give the variables the initial value of `np.random.randn()`, which [according to the documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.random.randn.html), generates a single floating point number when no arguments are given. The dimensions of your weight and bias tensors need to be supplied as arguments to `np.random.randn()`. Better yet, you can actually initialize these to random values in Tensorflow: `W = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([dim0, dim1], seed = seed)` (I always initialize random variables with a seed value for reproducibility)
- Just a note in case you don't know this already, but non-linear activation functions are required for neural networks to be effective. If all your activations are linear, then no matter how many layers you have, it will reduce to a simple linear regression in the end. Many people use relu activation for hidden layers. For the output layer, use softmax activation for multiclass classification problems where the output classes are exclusive (i.e., where only one class can be correct for any given input), and sigmoid activation for multiclass classification problems where the output classes are not exlclusive.

Answer (score 5):

Turns out, since this is a multi-class Linear Regression problem, and not a classification problem, that `tf.metrics.accuracy` is not the right approach.

Instead of displaying the accuracy of my model in terms of percentage, I instead focused on reducing the Mean Square Error (MSE) instead.

From looking at other examples, `tf.metrics.accuracy` is never used for Linear Regression, and only classification. Normally `tf.metric.mean_squared_error` is the right approach.

I implemented two ways of calculating the total MSE of my predictions to my testing data...

```
pred = tf.add(tf.matmul(X, W), b)
...
...
Y_pred = sess.run(pred, feed_dict={X:X_test})
mse = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(Y_pred - Y_test))
```

OR

```
mse = tf.metrics.mean_squared_error(labels=Y_test, predictions=Y_pred)
```

They both do the same but obviously the second approach is more concise.

There's a good explanation of how to measure the accuracy of a Linear Regression model [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47522433/4333347).

Answer (score 2):

I didn't think this was clear at all from the Tensorflow documentation, but you have to declare the accuracy operation, and then initialize all global and local variables, before you run the accuracy calculation:

```
accuracy, accuracy_op = tf.metrics.accuracy(labels=tf.argmax(Y_test, 0), predictions=tf.argmax(pred, 0))
# ...
init_global = tf.global_variables_initializer
init_local = tf.local_variables_initializer
sess.run([init_global, init_local])
# ...
# run accuracy calculation
```

I read something on Stack Overflow about the accuracy calculation using local variables, which is why the local variable initializer is necessary.

Comment: I tried implementing this but I'm still getting the error. Yeah the documentation is not the greatest and I can't find any examples of a working model that displays the models accuracy, the closest I got was getting the model to display its cost and MSE

Comment: Did you define the accuracy calculation before initializing the local variables?

Comment: No, after. I added the code in my edit part of my answer after the initialization.

Comment: Ok, I edited my question to add the complete code. I think I am most likely implementing `tf.metrics.accuracy` incorrectly but nevertheless.

Comment: The line where you declare the accuracy needs to be before you initialize the variables. I'm editing the answer for clarity.